# Customizing QwtPlot's scale and grid lines

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm confused with using **QwtPlot** class to draw a customized coordinate system.
My goal is to draw a coordinate system with customized scale, and draw grid line on these customized scales. Here are the values of the scales:

**x-axis and y-axis scale:**

```
x1=-0.642455
x2=0
x3=0.642455
y1=-0.642455
y2=0
y3=0.642455
```

I read the user's guide of [**QwtPlot** class](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html) and [**QwtPlotGrid** class](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_grid.html). I found a function in **QwtPlotGrid** class called **setxDiv** and seemed that it could help, So I wrote the following code:

```
QList<double> doubleListmin;//min scale
QList<double> doubleListmed;//medium scale
QList<double> doubleListmaj;//major scale
doubleListmin.append(0.1);
doubleListmed.append(0.3);
doubleListmaj.append(0.642455);
QList<double> doubleList[3];
doubleList[0] = doubleListmin;
doubleList[1] = doubleListmed;
doubleList[2] = doubleListmaj;
QwtScaleDiv *xDiv = new QwtScaleDiv(-0.642455, 0.642455, doubleList);
//lowerbound is -0.642455, upperbound is 0.642455, doubleList customizes the scale

QwtPlotGrid *grid = new QwtPlotGrid();
grid->setXDiv(*xDiv);
//grid->updateScaleDiv(*xDiv, *xDiv);
grid->attach(this);
```

But it turned out to have no influence on the new QwtPlotGrid, it doesn't change its scale system.

I think there's another way: draw a several lines in the QwtPlot. But I don't know how to do it.

Somebody help me please!!!
Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said "draw severalk lines" is not good approach because you can't do this lines infinity. To do this there is special class `QwtPlotMarker` which is more suitable here. Maybe not the best thing in the world, but works as you want:

```
        QwtPlotMarker *m1=new QwtPlotMarker;
        m1->setLinePen(QPen(Qt::gray));
        m1->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::VLine);
        m1->setValue(0,0);
        m1->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
        QwtPlotMarker *m2=new QwtPlotMarker;
        m2->setLinePen(QPen(Qt::gray));
        m2->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::HLine);
        m2->setValue(0,0);
        m2->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
        QwtPlotMarker *m3=new QwtPlotMarker;
        m3->setLinePen(QPen(Qt::gray));
        m3->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::HLine);
        m3->setValue(0,-0.642455);
        m3->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
        QwtPlotMarker *m4=new QwtPlotMarker;
        m4->setLinePen(QPen(Qt::gray));
        m4->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::HLine);
        m4->setValue(0,0.642455);
        m4->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
        QwtPlotMarker *m5=new QwtPlotMarker;
        m5->setLinePen(QPen(Qt::gray));
        m5->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::VLine);
        m5->setValue(-0.642455,0);
        m5->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
        QwtPlotMarker *m6=new QwtPlotMarker;
        m6->setLinePen(QPen(Qt::gray));
        m6->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::VLine);
        m6->setValue(0.642455,0);
        m6->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
```

[image]

Comment: Well,thanks!It works!And do you know how to clear these lines in a slot and replot this qwtplot with other lines?

Comment: @HYSuperman You can set new value `m6->setValue(0.642455*3,0);` or if you want to remove this lines, you can delete markers. For example. `        delete m1;
        delete m2;
        delete m4;
        delete m5;
        delete m3;
        delete m6;`

Comment: I know the delete way. But these lines are dynamicly created within a function in my QwtPlot class. I can't delete them outside the function, you see? I can't obtain there name outside the range of the function. So the next time I want to replot the whole QwtPlot, I need to have some functions in QwtPlot class which can clear all the lines on it. @Chernobyl

Comment: @HYSuperman of course your markers goes out if scope, so you can write markers as a class members, create then in function and delete everywhere in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Better create your own QwtScaleDiv object setting the ticks manually and assign them using QwtPlot::setAxisScaleDiv(). Update of the grid will happen automatically ( as long as you didn't decouple it explicitly ).

When you also need to manage the tick positions when zooming you have to derive your own scale engine instead - overloading the QwtScaleEngine::divideScale() method.